# How to split a string into a array of arrays of strings as fast as possible in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

**Short description:** Splitting a string takes way to long.

**Longer description:**
I need to **extract information from a string** looking like this:

```
...
5   1   12  1   1   1   466 1277    458 80  92  Assistance
2   1   13  0   0   0   1055    1277    1717    100 -1  
3   1   13  1   0   0   1055    1186    1717    191 -1  
4   1   13  1   1   0   1055    1277    1717    100 -1  
5   1   13  1   1   1   1055    1279    288 78  90  Vehicle
5   1   13  1   1   2   1489    1279    228 98  67  Lights
5   1   13  1   1   3   1856    1281    286 95  74  System
5   1   13  1   1   4   2284    1281    196 95  70  Apps
5   1   13  1   1   5   2618    1277    154 80  77  Info
...
```

(Side Note: the string comes as a return from the **page.GetTsvText(0)** method; page is a return of **TesseractEngine.Process(image)**; so the string contains information about **detected OCR strings**, **conficendes**, **bounding boxes coords**, etc.)

In order to be able to make easier use of the information, I wrote a method that **turns the string into a array of arrays of strings**:

```
private string[][] getDataArray(string source)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(source);

            string[] rows = source.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int nrOfRows = rows.Length;
            string[][] result = new string[nrOfRows][];

            for (int i = 0; i < nrOfRows; i++)
            {
                result[i] = rows[i].Split(new char[] { ' ', '   ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" $$$ getDataArray() took: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
            return result;
        }
```

**Note:** For some reason the string contains spaces that look longer than the usual spaces. I took it with copy-paste from the console log. It is a single character, not a tab, but it takes more space/ is wider than the usual space char.

**Problem:**

- When I measure the time **from inside** the method, it takes **less than 1 ms**.
- When I measure the time **from outside**, like this:

```
stopwatch.Restart();


// Get data
string[][] data = getDataArray(page.GetTsvText(0));

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(" $$$ $$$ Got data array in: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
```

it takes about **2000 ms**.

**Does the string initialisation take so long**? **How can I get it faster, like under 50 ms**?

Comment: How long does `page.GetTsvText(0)` take? you're not measuring things separately.

Comment: The outer one is just measuring the extra time `page.GetTsvText(0)` takes!

Comment: Outside the obvious measurement mistake already mentioned above, I'd like to throw in that using `string[][]` may not be the best of choices from a readability / maintainability standpoint.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: It took about 1800ms. So it takes the most part of the time. But the page is already processed by the engine. I was expecting it to be way faster.
Need to see how I can improve this. Thanks!

Comment: C# has a lot of overhead for error checking when calling a method.  The extra time is probably due to the error checking.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(source);` takes a relatively long time, especially for a long "source". So start the inner stopwatch *after* that to get a more accurate time

Comment: Can you cast that "long space" to an `int` and show the result? Curious about what space it really is (a TAB would be 9)

Answer (score 0):

By using Linq

```
string[][] result = source.Split('\n')
                          .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '   ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

**linq** has better performance and a faster result.